# Jenkins Job should trigger only on Pull request not on push or commit of branch

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am able to trigger the jenkins job on pull request from Bit-bucket, but the jobs trigger on push of the branch and commits too, which is not the ideal scenario.

> We have using POLL SCM: *which is blank*.
>
> Refspec: `+refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/*`
>
> Branch Specifier:`**`

Job Should only trigger on "Pull Request".

How can i disable to notify Jenkins not to trigger on push of the branch.

Please help

Comment: Which plugin are you using from the Bitbucket side?

Comment: we have not installed any plugin for Bitbucket in Jenknis. We have configured the Hooks in Bitbucket...using the GIT under SCM in jenkins and given Bitbucket repo url.

Comment: I asked about plugins (hooks) at the Bitbucket side... which hook are you using in Bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

We have used Webhook in bitbucket for pull request..

Answer (score -1):

Just to give an alternate approach, if you rather not build your own notification pipeline, consider using [LightFlare](https://lightflare.bytebeacon.com) (I'm the creator) that has out of the box support of consuming Webhooks events from many services (bitbucket included) and notifies you at your choice(s) of destinations (slack / email etc ...).

We have a support for notifying your webhooks as well (like call back to jenkins). In this case you get analytics and notifications as added bonus.